# How to output decision tree data in sklearn

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Is there a way to output decision tree data, e.g. as a dictionary? I'm aware of `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz`, which is a great visual, but I was wondering if there was a way to output, say, this:

[image]

as this:

```
{0: 'samples': 100.0%, 'value': [0.53, 0.47],
 1: 'samples': 72.6%, 'value': [0.61, 0.39],
 2: 'samples': 27.4%, 'value': [0.38, 0.62]}
```

Having the data as a `dictionary`, `DataFrame`, `array`, etc. would make it easier to analyze, rather than just looking at some colored boxes. I've looked through the `sklearn` documentation but couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an implementation for this [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/79bdc8f711d0af225ed6be9fdb708cea9f98a910/sklearn/tree/export.py). After playing with it, I think one of the limiting factors is the depth of a dict like this. Remember that a tree like this isn't:

```
{node1:[data],
 node2:[data],
 node3:[data],
 etc}
```

It's more like:

```
{node1:[data],
      sub-node1:{
                 sub-sub-node1:{
                                sub-sub-sub-node1:[data],sub-sub-sub-node2:[data],...}
                 sub-sub-node2:{
                                sub-sub-sub-node1:[data],sub-sub-sub-node2:[data],...}
                 etc}
      sub-node2:{etc}
}
```

Which can quickly get out of hand if you have a tree with high (or `None`) `max_depth`

Comment: The sklearn.tree.export_dict() function seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to call it (keep getting an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'export_dict').

Tree depth isn't an issue in my case, since I've set max_depth = 2

Comment: As far as I can tell, this function was never included in a major release. I was able to just copy-paste it from that repo, including the import at the top (changed from `from . import _tree` to `from sklearn.tree import _tree`) and run it as a regular function, passing in a fitted DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: This worked! The dictionary itself is a bit unwieldy, but it's something. Thanks, G!